# Neo4j: Get all nodes in a graph, even those that are unconnected by relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Cypher how can I get all nodes in a graph? I am running some testing against the graph and I have some nodes without relationships so am having trouble crafting a query.

The reason I want to get them all is that I want to delete all the nodes in the graph at the start of every test.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

So, this gives you all nodes:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n;
```

If you want to delete everything from a graph, you can do something like this:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() 
DELETE n, r;
```

Updated for 2.0+

Edit:
Now in 2.3 they have `DETACH DELETE`, so you can do something like:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n;
```

Comment: Will this delete the root node? I want to keep him.

Comment: Ok, then add `where ID(n) <> 0` after the `match`.

Answer (score 14):

Would this work for you?

```
START a=node:index_name('*:*')
```

Assuming you have an index with these orphaned nodes in them.

Comment: Thanks Jason, never seen that syntax before +1

Comment: The syntax is referenced here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-start.html#start-node-by-index-query

Answer (score 7):

This just works fine in 2.0:

```
    MATCH n RETURN n
```

Comment: Using neo4j, parentheses are mandatory : `MATCH (n) RETURN n;`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete some large number of objects from the graph, one needs to be mindful of the not building up such a large single transaction such that a Java OUT OF HEAP Error will be encountered.

If your nodes have more than 100 relationships per node ((100+1)*10k=>1010k deletes) reduce the batch size or see the recommendations at the bottom.

> With 4.4 and newer versions you can utilize the CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS syntax.

```
MATCH (n:Foo) where n.foo='bar'
CALL { WITH n
DETACH DELETE n
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS;
```

> With 3.x forward and using APOC

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (n:Foo) where n.foo='bar' return id(n) as id", "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = id DETACH DELETE n", {batchSize:10000})
yield batches, total return batches, total
```

For best practices around deleting huge data in neo4j, follow these [guidelines](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/large-delete-transaction-best-practices-in-neo4j/).